# Is there a way to convert a conditional (if/for) statements to a variable?

Tags: python-3.x

I've written some code

```
for i in range(0, b):
    for g in range(1, b+1):
        if i+1==g:
            a = f'''r{g} = {list(df.iloc[i])}<br>'''
```

I want to be able to store this exact code in a variable and be able to print it out/write it to a file (and hopefully be able to convert it into regular code again)

Just to clarify, I want to be able to print that exact piece of code/write that piece of code to a file

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The way that you store a fragment of code for later use is to define a function.

Comment: I want to be able to print that exact code/write it to a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store these lines of code in a function and then can get back its source code with the help of `inspect` library as follows:

```py
import inspect


def foo(arg1, arg2):
    # do something with args
    a = arg1 + arg2
    return a


lines = inspect.getsource(foo)
print(lines)
```

So if you wanna run these lines of code, just call the function, and if you wanna print these lines of code, just use inspect library.

And if you also want these lines of code to get written in another python file, just do as follows

```py
file=open("Program.py","w")
file.write(lines) 
#lines is the output of the above program
file.close()
```

And you would also be able to execute this python file!!

Hope I made myself clear

Comment: While this partially solved my issue, using print(lines) is printing the code along with ```def my_func():``` Any idea on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add it in a function, like this

```
def my_function(df, b):
for i in range(0, b):
    for g in range(1, b+1):
        if i+1==g:
            a = f'''r{g} = {list(df.iloc[i])}<br>'''
```

And later if you want to call the function, just call my_function(df, b)

Comment: I want to be able to print that exact piece of code or write it to a file

Comment: @RedFox Open a file like `file=open("a.py","w")` and just do `file.write(code)` and close this file. code is the string form of the program (output of my answer).

Comment: a.py file would also be able to execute

Comment: As Sam mentioned earlier
import inspect
lines = inspect.getsource(my_function)
print(lines)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about inspect. It was able to solve my issue

Comment: Welcome, let me also update so that others may also be able to know about all this

Comment: @RedFox In order to remove `def my_func()` from output of my answer, just split the output of my program with `():` as the separator (I hope `():` has not been used anywhere inside function), and get the element at index 1, it is your answer. Should I write its code also?

Comment: But splitting the output doesn't remove the indent does it?

Comment: Here is the solution to tackle this problem `print(lines.split(":")[1].replace("    ", ""))`

Comment: Just replace tab space with empty string

Comment: @RedFox Working for you??

Comment: Yeah, I had already tried replace, it removes all indent